# How do I select all, when the last selection is deselected in R / Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

How do I select all, when the last selection in a checkboxGroupInput is deselected?

I have tried:

```
if (input$checkboxGroupInput == NULL){

      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "checkboxGroupInput",
                               choices = year,
                               selected = year,
                               inline = TRUE)

    }
```

But it returns: "Warning: Unhandled error in observer: argument is of length zero"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct way to check if an element of a list is NULL. Your way returns `logical(0)` which when evaluated in the if statement throws the error you got. The correct way is `is.null()`, which either returns TRUE or FALSE.

```
> test <- list(foo=1)
> is.null(test$bar)
[1] TRUE
> test$bar == NULL
logical(0)
```

your first line should be:

```
if ( is.null(input$checkboxGroupInput) ) {
  ...
}
```